# Getting around the CSS height issues

Tags: html, css, height

Ok, so, anyone who has worked with css and html for long enough has probably dealt with the ridiculous issues of "height:100%". I've read some stuff on dealing with it, but it hasn't helped much. Below is a layout that I need to construct. I'm hoping that a good answer will help me with most other structures requiring height.
Rules:

- It must *fill* the browser window without giving any scrollbars.
- The heights of the containers must not go beyond the visible area (i.e. not requiring "overflow:hidden" on the html or body tags just to remove scrollbars)
- The FLEX areas should be adjustable to given *pixel* measurements, whereas the FILLER should fill whatever area is left available to it.
- All areas should be strictly sized such that their content should be cut off when overflowing, without making the area any bigger.
- If possible, I'd *prefer* to do it without "position:fixed" or "position:absolute", in case any time later I need such a structure inside some other wrapper, but for now I'll be glad if it's possible in any way.
- Lastly, I really don't want to use javascript for it.

```
+-------------------------------------------+
|                  FLEX /\                  |
|                       \/                  |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
|                                   |       |
|                                   |       |
|                                   |       |
|                                   |       |
|               /\                  |       |
|           < FILLER >              | FLEX  |
|               \/                  | <- -> |
|                                   |       |
|                                   |       |
|                                   |       |
|                                   |       |
+-----------------------------------+-------+
```

**EDIT:**
 So far I found that I could achieve what @cimmanon was saying in his second example, plus eliminating the excess space on the side of the header. I did this by creating two tables (one for wrapping both the header and the other table, which wraps the content and sidebar), a bad practice. But if it's the only way to do it (while trying to stick with classic css, and avoid using hacks like flexbox), then I'm sticking with it.

**I've still got one problem,** which is also found in @cimmanon's second example: One of my rules state: *All areas should be strictly sized such that their content should be cut off when overflowing, without making the area any bigger.*. After adding a bunch of random boxes to each of the containers, I discovered that they push out the bottom two containers beyond the browser's bottom, creating a scrollbar. This is because of the annoying concept that height:100% means the browser's viewport height, or the content's height if it's taller - which in this case it is.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant way to go about this is using Flexbox.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/rifzt

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#layout {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  /* fix for old Firefox */
  width: 100%;
}

#layout header {
  height: 10em;
  background: #ffffcc;
}

.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 auto;
  flex: 1 auto;
  /* fix for old Firefox */
  width: 100%;
}

#layout article {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

#layout aside {
  width: 15em;
  background: #ccccff;
}

<article id="layout">
  <header>
    <h1>Header Title</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <article>
      <h1>Another Title</h1>

      <p>...</p>
    </article>

    <aside>
      <h1>Aside Title</h1>

      <p>...</p>
    </aside>
  </div>
</article>
```

http://caniuse.com/flexbox

You could do this with the table/table-row/table-cell display properties instead, but you'll have to add a lot of extra markup to get it to work.

This *almost* works, but the header doesn't quite span the full width of the viewport.  If you add enough elements, you might be able to do it.

http://tinker.io/38b0d

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
}

header {
    height: 10em;
    display: table-row;
}

article {
    display: table-row;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: grey;
}

article div, article aside {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
}

article aside {
    width: 10em;
    background: orange;
}

<header>Header</header>

<article>
    <div class="main">
        Remaining Space
    </div>

    <aside>
        Sidebar
    </aside>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

give a fixed height to your wrapper and then divide height of flex and filler using percentage
(eg.flex=25% and filler=75%)
or
you will have to use javascript(window.innerHeight) for getting the height of window that page is viewed in.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I made it clear: the FLEX areas should have a given pixel size - percentages will let them stretch.

Comment: so you only want your filler to be responsive,not the flex??

Comment: Yes. Correct - only the filler will change width and height on window resizing.